# Selenium & Python: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, connection

My function looks like this:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

def test_alpha(browser, sitename):
    browser.get(sitename)
    if 1:
        browser.quit()
        return 1
    else:
        browser.quit()
        return 0


def test_beta():
    sitename_1 = "https://www.google.com/"
    sitename_2 = "https://www.youtube.com/"
    chrome = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python36\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe")

    if test_alpha (chrome, sitename_1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

    if test_alpha (chrome, sitename_2):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

When it opens the first webpage (google.com), everything works fine. It closes the browser, and when it goes through the second call of test_alpha (when it has to open youtube.com), I get an error saying that "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I've tried turning off windows firewall and my antivirus but it still doesn't work.
Also tried to use browser.quit() along with killing the chrome.exe process. Still doesn't work.

Comment: by calling `browser.quit()` you are killing the webbrowser process so it is no longer listening for selenium to connect. you either need to repeat the webdriver line or not `quit` the driver.

Comment: `.close()` instead should work

Comment: @JamesKent it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: @redp it kinda works, but if I open a single tab the first time and I use .close(), then I will have no session to use. Thank you too!